# Why after excluding the singularity from the numerical integration the problem persists. Is this result trustable

Tags: numerical-integration

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ph = 0.33
rs = 20
R = 8.5
r[s_, l_, b_] := Sqrt[R^2 + s^2 + 2 s R Cos[l] Cos[b]]
NIntegrate[{ph/((r[s, l, b]/rs) (1 + r[s, l, b]/rs)^2)} Sin[l], {s, 
0, \[Infinity]}, {l, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
Exclusions -> {r[s, l, b] == 0}]
```

After doing this also i am facing NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
And there remains an uncertainity of the result being true.
Is this result trustable?

Comment: You have constants that differ by **dozens of orders of magnitude**, which will make numerical calculations slow and unreliable. Please, work in **natural units**, where all constants are of order 1. Thanks.

Comment: Is `M` supposed to be a matrix? What is the purpose of all those braces `{{...}}`? Note that in Mathematica, parentheses are `(...)`, not `{...}` or `[...]`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Ok It is true the great value of constants making it bit tougher to calculate but in the case of natural unit system also there remains some problems so is this answer trustable?

Comment: I am 93.4% sure the integral is zero.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for pointing out the mistake of taking the limit from 0 to 2Pi it should be 0 to Pi